# PsExec and Java to connect to a remote Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, psexec

I have a requirement where I need to connect to a Windows Server from another personal windows machine. I also need to be able to CD into a particular folder on the remote machine, get a list of files in that folder and check for the existence of a file in that folder. When I started researching about this, I could understand that there are two options:

- Have OpenSSH installed on the windows server and use clients like JSch to connect - my infra team may or may not approve this request.
- Use PsExec to connect and do a similar thing - here is where I am able to connect but not able to figure out how to CD to a directory and get a list of files in any folder there.

Here is what I have in terms of code:

```
    private static void authenticateAndExecute() {
    String psCommand = PATH_TO_PSEXEC + "\\PsExec.exe \\\\" + "testdev19" + " -u " + "userName"
            + " -p " + "password";
    psCommand = psCommand + " " + "cmd cd c:\\destdir" + " dir ";
    String[] cmd = new String[5];
    cmd[0] = "cmd.exe";
    cmd[1] = "/C";
    cmd[2] = psCommand;
    cmd[3] = "";
    cmd[4] = "";
    // Run remote command
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null);
        System.out.println("Connected..." + p.getOutputStream());
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();

        InputStream es = p.getErrorStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        BufferedReader errReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(es));
        String line;

        // Read STDOUT into a buffer.
        while ((line = errReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        // If no STDOUT check STDERR.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        // Wait for the process to end.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (p != null) {
            p.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

All I see after this is run is that the process has ended with a return code of 0. I want to see the list of files in the destination directory. Is this even possible using PsExec or am I going in the wrong path ?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Can't you use file sharing?  `\\testdev19\c$\destdir` should show you the files in that folder.

Comment: Thanks Harry for your suggestion but unfortunately, I need to do this over 500+ servers and not all server owners would allow the sharing of a folder. That's the reason, I would like to do this programmatically using Java since I am more comfortable in that language !

Comment: FYI, in my experience, if file sharing is turned off, psexec won't work either.  There may be edge cases, I'm not sure of the details.  (But speaking as a system administrator myself, I'd much rather give someone access to a suitably constrained file share than give them administrator access via psexec!)

Comment: But to answer your original question, the command would have to look something like `psexec \\target cmd /c "cd /d c:\destdir & dir"`

Comment: Tried this on both command line and program but neither seemed to work - the program gives me a list of files in the project folder that the java class is executing in and not the files in the destination folder specified. The command line test doesn't return anything at all. Not sure what I am doing wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at:

```
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/programmatically_connecting_to_remote_systems2?lang=en
```

that might solve your problem

Comment: Please provide the details of the answer in the post instead of just providing a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
String psCommand = "<path_of_psexec>/psexec.exe \\\\"+currentServerHostname + " -u " + currentServerUser + " -p " + currentServerPass;
      psCommand = psCommand + " " + commandToRunOnRemoteMachine + " " + parameters;
      String[] cmd = new String[5];
      cmd[0]="cmd.exe";
      cmd[1]="/C";
      cmd[2]=psCommand;
      cmd[3]="";
      cmd[4]="";
      // Run remote command
      File f = new File(getCurrentWorkingDirectory() + "\\lib");
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,f);
```